# ngFor matching key Value

Tags: angular

In angular 6, with ngFor,  Is it possible to match key value and print 
when it's match?

Below is my JSON, I want to match SportName and print Name for matching record

For example, I want to do check sportName = "shooting Indoor" and print Name="Ian" only.  Rest should get ignored.

```
[{
  "SportName": "football Outdoor",
  "Name": "Ami",
}, {
  "SportName": "shooting Indoor",
  "Name": "Ian",
}, {
  "SportName": "hockey Outdoor",
  "Name": "Jeo",
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use code like this (I write from head) - I assume your array is in `this.list`

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list">
    <div *ngIf="item.SportName =='shooting Indoor' ">
        {{ item.Name }}
    </div>
</dvi>
```

If you don't wanna generate `<div>` nodes use `<ng-container>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have `sports` in your Component:

```
...
sports = [
  { "SportName": "football Outdoor", "Name": "Ami" },
  { "SportName": "shooting Indoor", "Name": "Ian" },
  { "SportName": "hockey Outdoor", "Name": "Jeo" }
];
...
```

Use **`ng-container`** along with **`*ngFor`** and **`*ngIf`** and check for the condition in **`*ngIf`**

```
<div *ngFor="let sport of sports">
    <ng-container *ngIf="sport.SportName === 'shooting Indoor' && sport.Name='Ian'">
        {{ sport.Name }}
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

**OR**

You could use **`[ngStyle]`**:

```
<div 
  *ngFor="let sport of sports" 
  [ngStyle]="{ display : (sport.SportName === 'shooting Indoor' && sport.Name='Ian') ? 'block': 'none' }">
  {{ sport.Name }}
</div>
```

Comment: This is better than using divs. `ng-container` isolates variables used in the html.